# scala: shortest way to convert List[ Tuple3[A,B,C] ] to Foo(A, B, List[C])

Tags: list, scala, mapping, instance, one-to-many

I have a query result of List[ Tuple3[User, Order, OrderItem] ]

To create a case class instance of an Invoice, its companion object takes a User, Order and a List[OrderItem].

Currently I'm hacking it out something like:

```
def getInvoice(orderNum: String): Option[Invoice] = {

  val res = 
    dao.byOrderNum(orderNum) // List[ Tuple3[User, OrderEntry, OrderItem] ]

  if(!res.isEmpty) {
    val(user, order) = (res(0)._1, res(0)._2)
    val items = res map { case(_, _, oi: OrderItem) => oi }
    Some( Invoices.apply(user, order, items) ) // gets an Invoice
  }
  else None
}
```

I could make the query result a `List[ Option[Tuple3[User, Order, OrderItem]] ]`, which would let me flatMap over the result, but not sure what that buys me.

At any rate, must be a more concise/elegant solution to the problem

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following should be exactly equivalent:

```
def getInvoice(orderNum: String): Option[Invoice] = {
  val res = dao.byOrderNum(orderNum)

  res.headOption.map {
    case (user, order, _) => Invoices(user, order, res.map(_._3))
  }
}
```

The key is `headOption`, which handles the checking for emptiness in a more idiomatic way (it gives `None` for an empty sequence and `Some(xs.head)` for a non-empty one).

Comment: generally speaking, is it better to work with List[T] results vs. List[ Option[T] ]? I've setup my dao's list[T](query) to return a List[T] and not sure if that will limit me/cause problems...

Comment: What would the semantics of your `List[Option[T]]` be? Specifically, what would `None` mean?

Comment: exactly, you could flatMap over it to get...List[T], maybe better to just start with List[T] in the first place ;-) I'm rolling with Option[T] for single row results and List[T] otherwise. That headOption is going to come in handy for 1-to-many relationships, thanks for the gem!

Answer (score 4):

The `headOption` thing is neat and you might as well use it since it's there, but you could simply pattern match on the List (rather than mapping an Option), which is kind of what you in the question, but it just needs a bit of tidying up:

```
res match {
  case (a, b, _) :: _ => Some(Invoices(a, b, res.map(_._3)))
  case _              => None
}
```

Comment: +1, that is absurd, how does the compiler know to match the first row of the tuple List? I would expect case(a,b) to be bound to List[A], List[B]

Comment: If `res` would be a `Tuple3` this code would work fine, but because it is a `List[Tuple3]` it does not work.

Comment: @virtualeyes `::` here is an extractor object, giving nice syntax for extracting Lists. In pattern matching, `A(b, c)` can be written `b A c`, so this is the same as `case ::((a, b, _), _) => ...`.

Comment: @sschaef you've missed the extractor.

Comment: @LuigiPlinge indeed, we both missed :: ;-) On the fence, headOption I can revisit later and know what's going on. :: a few weeks down the road, not so sure (unless I'm using it often enough to get it ingrained)

Comment: @virtualeyes You don't really need to know it works "under the hood"; just that it looks like the List declaration syntax. But you definitely should be able to use it, as it's a used extensively in even the simplest functional problems. Have a play around with http://aperiodic.net/phil/scala/s-99/

Comment: @LuigiPlinge that link is the last thing I need with this looming deadline, but yes, bookmarked and to-explore over the weekend. I agree, it just works (confirmed). I do need to embrace symbols as I plan on diving into Scalaz, which is of course symbolic soup for the functionally enlightened ;-)